# What does this script do? (part of Western Digital Website)

Tags: javascript

I found this as a part od Western Digital website. I want to know what does it do. please help.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-20073-2']);
_gaq.push (['_gat._anonymizeIp']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Comment: This creates a script tag and add it to the header of the page, for Google Analytics visitors statistics.

Comment: *"What does this script do?"* is not a very useful question. Which part don't you understand? And what have you done to find the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Its a [Google Anayltics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) script - 
It sends data about visitors for reporting

Answer (score 0):

That's just google analytics tracking code.